# How to use in environment variable in packages.config?

Tags: c#, nuget, config, nuget-package

I have a class library project in C#

I want to set version of a nuget package by environment variable.

I've tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Package" version="%version%" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

but I'm getting error

```
packages.config': Invalid package version for package id
```

How can I set the version by some variable?
Thank you.

Comment: Why? When are you resolving the value? This sounds like an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: The version is normally specified on the command line. Show us the command you use to build the package.

Comment: @PMF - I run the project by right click -> rebuild. No command line

Comment: I recommend using a build system then (such as nuke) or at least a prebuild step. These will also help you with automatically creating version numbers from the source control history.